# Styling separate elements on a page in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

Using Wordpress I am designing a theme for a client's website.

I have set the landing/home page to a static page, and I'm using `front-page.php` as the default template for this.

My question is how can I style individual elements on the page when all of the page content is called in at once using `<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>`

Currently I multiple `<div>`'s in the WP page content editor like so:

[image: Example: using WP content editor to edit page content.]

However, I'm concerned that my client or something else, may delete this content by accident and completely spoil the design. How can I separate content and style it accordingly in my template?

Comment: add this directly to the `font-page.php`

Comment: Also you should be looking at using metaboxes within wordpress for a client site allowing them to control their own content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can I style individual elements on the page?

There are always [body classes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) you can use for different pages/posts.

> How can I separate content and style it accordingly in my template?

There are few options depend on what you need:

- Turn off "Visual" editor mode for each user account. It sort of helps.
- Move the custom HTML into the template files. If that's OK.
- Use [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), preferably with Advanced custom fields [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

Answer (score 0):

For every page,if you need the alone class then function :body_class() : is sufficient.
Syntax :- < body < ?php body_class(); ?> > 
and you can also implement the another function : post_class : for the loop class.
Syntax :- < body < ?php post_class(); ?> >